# export odbc/database (data dictionary) into excel

Tags: excel, odbc

I have searched high and low for ways to report back / export the data dictionary that already exists in my database. All I can find are one line codes but I have no clue how to implement that into something i can work with.

Right now I access my database in Excel using MS Query. I create my own "reports" in excel using formulas and functions. I need a Bible (of sorts) to look for fields in each table. Within MS Query I can View the data dictionary but I would prefer to dump the entire thing.

Someone somewhere along the way created one, which i use today but it is outdated and I would like to find out how to do it myself.

Comment: You're using 10 (or 20...) years old approach. Embrace .NET to work effectively with M$

Comment: Please provide some code or trials you made, so that we can help you better.